Need suggestions on getting data from odoo inside Django on user navigation
I am developing a Complaint Management System with the admin side in Odoo and the subscriber side in Django. All complaints and subscriber information are managed on the admin/Odoo side, while the Django side is used solely for subscriber registration and recording of complaints.
I need suggestions on what technology or methodology to use to retrieve subscriber information from Odoo when a subscriber logs in. There are various links where subscribers can click to view their information, which is retrieved from Odoo.
These options are coming in my mind

XML-RPC read ().The simplest option is to read specific form data from Odoo and display it in a Django form when users click on certain links.

Django Channels

Observable.


I Appreciate clear guidance which technology stack I should use.
